# Recursive function to do depth first-search

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function initialized from the command line that takes a text file with a series of starting points, end points, and distances between these points and then finds the shortest possible distance from a particular starting point to a particular end point.

For example a text file would look something like this:

```
a,b,5
a,c,8
b,d,6
c,d,2
d,e,12
d,f,2
e,g,3
f,g,7
```

and would be invoked with something like:

```
python program_name.py a b text_file_name.txt
```

The idea from this is based on a project from an upcoming class I am going to be taking next term that I want to get a head start on. The professor provided an extensive 'start code' found [here](https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/15F/cis210/assignments/base/routing/routes.py).

I have tried multiple different ways to implement the recursive function to move through the text file and record and compare the distances between points but I can't seem to get it right. Right now I have a (very obviously incorrect) code of:

```
if place not in distances:
    print('not in')
    distances[place] =roads[place]
    dist_so_far = distances[place]     
    dfs(place, 0.0, roads, distances)
elif place in distances and distances[place] <= dist_so_far:
    print('less than')
    #dfs(place,0.0, roads, distances)
elif place in distances and distances[place] > dist_so_far:
    print('greater than')
    distances[place] = dist_so_far
    dfs(place, 0.0, roads, distances)
```

I know this isn't right, I just think the format of it is a good starting point. I just can't seem to understand which dictionaries contain what and what indices to compare.

Comment: Just a heads up, you shouldn't put course projects on stackoverflow. Professors will find you.

Comment: But since this isn't a class assignment but a personal project that he's tackling on his own to get a head start on the class, it's actually on-topic for Stack Overflow. Unlike most "please do my homework for me" questions that we get, the OP here is actually trying to do the work on his own and asking for help about the things he doesn't understand. Well done, @Crakajaxz.

Comment: @rmunn spot on, thank you. I also noticed on that assignment page that there's a place for Authors so if this does end up being a project next term  I plan on linking this question to provide proper documentation. not trying to hide anything or cheat

Comment: @Crakajaxz - That is an *excellent* attitude, and that's precisely why I felt motivated to write you a detailed answer. Also, if you need more help than what I just gave you, you should ask it as a separate question, since Stack Overflow prefers that each question be about one topic and that each person post only one answer. If you do ask a separate question, feel free to post a comment here mentioning my username (like you just did) and providing a link to your new question. I'd be very happy to answer it as well.

Answer (score 2):

> I just can't seem to understand which dictionaries contain what and what indexes to compare and it's driving me wild!

I'll take a shot at explaining the [starting-point code that your professor posted](https://www.cs.uoregon.edu/Classes/15F/cis210/assignments/base/routing/routes.py) and what it's doing, without giving you the solution on a silver platter (because you'll learn more by solving it yourself).

```
def read_distances(map_file):
    connections = dict()
    # ....
    return connections
```

This function is building a dictionary that you can use to look up whether any two points are connected to each other, and the distance between them. So if there's a line "A,B,5" in the input text file, the result of `read_distances` will have two entries created, one for A with value `("B",5)`, and one for B with value `("A",5)`. Also note that *each* entry in that dictionary will be a *list* of connections. In other words:

```
# Assume that map_file contained one line: "A,B,5"
distances = read_distances(map_file)
print(distances["A"])  # Will print "[('B',5)]"
print(distances["B"])  # Will print "[('A',5)]"
```

If there were more than one connection, e.g. if the text file contained:

```
A,B,5
A,C,3
B,C,4
```

Then you'd get something like:

```
distances = read_distances(map_file)
print(distances["A"])  # Will print "[('B',5),('C',3)]"
print(distances["B"])  # Will print "[('A',5),('C',4)]"
print(distances["C"])  # Will print "[('A',3),('B',4)]"
```

So when you get `distances[starting_point]`, you get a **list** of all points that have a single connection to your starting point. That list consists of 2-tuples (that is, tuples with 2 elements), each of which has the structure (other_point, distance_as_int).

I think I'll stop here, as this is probably *just* enough help to get you past your current problem without solving the exercise for you. (I just deleted a section that I'd written saying "Here's how I suggest solving this", because I realized that I shouldn't give you that help unless you ask for it.) If you need more help, leave a comment on this answer (or on your question) and I should get a notification. I'd be glad to help you more with this, especially since you're taking the right approach in trying to solve it yourself before the class even starts.

---

**Update 1:**

Okay, one more tip that won't solve the problem for you. When you look up `distances[starting_point]` and get a list of tuples, you'll want to iterate through that list doing something with each tuple. E.g.,

```
connections = distances[start_point]
for connection in connections:
    end_point = connection[0]
    distance = connection[1]
    # Now do something with start_point, end_point, and distance
    # Precisely *what* you'll do with them is up to you
```

That code can be simplified a bit, because Python has a nice "tuple unpacking" feature: if you're looping over something that produces tuples, like your "connections" list, you can do this:

```
connections = distances[start_point]
for end_point, distance in connections:
    # Now do something with start_point, end_point, and distance
    # Precisely *what* you'll do with them is up to you
```

And that will automatically "unpack" the tuple for you. Note that this ONLY works if you know that all the tuples you'll get will have the same number of items (2 in this case). There's one further thing that we can do, which is to notice that we don't *really* need that `connections` variable since we're not using it except to loop over. Eliminate that, and the code becomes:

```
for end_point, distance in distances[start_point]:
    # Now do something with start_point, end_point, and distance
    # Precisely *what* you'll do with them is up to you
```

And that's the clearest, most "Pythonic" way to code that particular loop.

**NOTE:** The above code won't actually run as-is, because Python requires that any loop has to have at least one statement in it, and comments don't count as statements. To make that code actually run, you would have to include the `pass` statement in the loop. The `pass` statement is a special statement that is just a "no-op", that is, it does absolutely nothing. So to **actually** run the code above that does nothing in the loop, you'd write:

```
for end_point, distance in distances[start_point]:
    # Now do something with start_point, end_point, and distance
    # Precisely *what* you'll do with them is up to you
    pass
```

And that loop will be allowed, whereas the code without the word `pass` would produce an `IndentationError`. I left `pass` out in all my examples above for simplicity, but I figured it's worth mentioning why that code won't run precisely as-is.

---

**Update 2:**

As requested, here's a function that will solve this, so that you can go through step by step and understand what's going on. I've put in extensive comments, but without the comments, this would be just eight lines of code.

```
def dfs(place, dist_so_far, roads, distances):
    """Depth-first search, which may continue from from_place if dist_so_far
        is the shortest distance at which it has yet been reached.
       Args:
          place: Currently searching from here
          dist_so_far:  Distance at which from_place has been reached
              this time (which may not be the shortest path to from_place)
          roads:  dict mapping places to lists of hops of the form (place, hop-distance)
          distances: dict mapping places to the shortest distance at which they
               have been reached so far (up to this time).
    """
    #FIXME
    #   Consider cases:
    #      - We've never been at place before (so it's not in distances)
    #      - We've been at place before, on a path as short as this one (in distances)
    #      - We've been here before, but this way is shorter (dist_so_far)
    #    Consider which are base cases, and which require recursion.
    #    For the cases that require recursion, what is the progress step?

    # First scenario: we've never reached this place before
    if place not in distances:
        # Right now we only know one way to get to this place,
        # so that's automatically the shortest known distance.
        distances[place] = dist_so_far

    # Second scenario: we've been here before, via a route
    # that was shorter than dist_so_far. If so, then any
    # roads from here lead to places we've also already
    # visited via a shorter route. Any distance we calculate
    # right now would just be longer than the distance we've
    # already found, so we can just stop right now!
    if dist_so_far > distances[place]:
        return

    # Third scenario: dist_so_far is actually the shortest
    # path we've found yet. (The first scenario is actually
    # a special case of this one!) We should record the
    # shortest distance to this place, since we'll want to
    # use that later. Then we'll look at all the roads from
    # this place to other places, and for each of those
    # other places, we'll make a recursive call to figure
    # out more paths.

    # Note no "if" statement needed: because of the return
    # statement earlier, if we get here, we know that the
    # current route is the best one yet known.
    distances[place] = dist_so_far

    # Now for some recursion:
    for other_place, hop_distance in roads[place]:
        dist_to_other_place = dist_so_far + hop_distance
        dfs(other_place, dist_to_other_place, roads, distances)

    # That's it!
```

And yes, that's really it. I ran this against the sample distances file you provided, and it finds the shortest possible distance for each pair of points. Try running through the algorithm step-by-step in your head and see if you understand why this works.

One **key** concept for you to understand, though, may not be immediately obvious when you first look at this. That key concept is: **Python dictionaries are persistent and mutable**. That is, if you pass a dictionary object (like the `distances` dictionary in this example) to a function, and that function modifies the dictionary, **the dictionary you passed to the function will be modified**.

By the way, professional programmers tend to consider this a **BAD** thing, because calling a function shouldn't unexpectedly modify your parameters. That tends to cause subtle, hard-to-track down bugs in your program, and should generally be avoided. (Note the word **unexpectedly** in that sentence, though. If the function you're calling is named `add_value_to_dict`, then you're probably *expecting* your dictionary to be modified.)

However, in this particular case, the dictionary-modification effect, that is usually considered a **bad** side-effect, is key to writing efficient code. The `distances` dictionary is being used to keep track of what we've found so far, and to see if there's any work left to do. Since you're expecting it to be modified by the recursive calls to `dfs()`, you're not creating subtle bugs for yourself. But I don't want you to get the idea that the technique used here, of modifying a dictionary that was passed in as a parameter to your function, is a good idea all the time. Most of the time, it will lead to subtle bugs that you won't discover until months later.

All right, that's probably enough explanation. See if you can step through this code in your head and understand it. If there's anything that puzzles you, let me know.

Comment: @Crakajaxz - I think your now-deleted comment got mangled somehow. Note that comments are just one-liners, and don't let you press Enter in the middle. However, maybe I just answered your question when I updated my answer just now; let me know.

Comment: Thank you for not giving me the solution straight away, i appreciate that! Your explanation cleared up a big source of confusion for me. 

So in this case if start_point was 'a' roads[start_point] would be [(b,5),(c,8)] and if i assigned distances[start_point]=roads[start_point] then I would get {a: [(b,5),(c,8)]}

what I am confused about is where dist_so_far comes into the mix. How do i assign the current distance from start_point to another point in that variable? where does it come in in relation to distances.

Maybe post the very very beginning of your suggestion to give me a sirection?

Comment: I think your edit may have just partially answered my question of how to specify which part of the tuple i want to be assigned ton a certain variable too, so thank you. I will continue to do some testing and see what i come up with!

Comment: @Crakajaxz - I just realized that the "how I would do it" suggestion I had written and then deleted turns out to actually be a **breadth-first** search, and your professor is asking you to do a **depth-first** search. So I think I'd better refrain from posting it.

Comment: In case you're not familiar with the difference yet: a **depth-first** search of a maze would explore a single path as far as possible, then back up just enough to find the first alternate path. A **breadth-first** search would search every branch as soon as it was found. See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F6oYjQc_tNM for a good visualization of both kinds of searching.

Comment: Thank you, I believe what I'm having trouble with now is trying to bring the dist_so_far variable into the equation . I know I can break down the tuples to assign each of the values to dist_so_far, but then how would i compare those dist_so_far values to find the shortest route later on? I'm trying to look ahead and I don't quite understand how to deconstruct them in a way that fits within the needs for the proper outcome.

Comment: In the `dfs()` code that your professor posted, it's not `dist_so_far` that's going to keep track of your shortest routes, it's the `distances` dictionary. `dist_so_far` is going to be *how far you've **come** since the original starting point*. E.g., if you're currently at A and there's a path from A to B with distance 5, you'll end up calling `dfs("B", dist_so_far+5, roads, distances)` at some point. Then when you get out of that recursive call, look at `distances["A"]` and `distances["B"]` and see if those two differ by more than 5. Does that help?

Comment: Ahhh, yes that does make sense now! I'm beginning to better understand the purpose of all of these variables, but honestly I'm still pretty stumped on how to write the code to properly make this function. I'm not sure what to index or what to compare. feel like I haven't made very much progress.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93956/discussion-between-crakajaxz-and-rmunn).